# Difference between pre and post incrementation with example

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compiler-errors

given  `float ar[] = {0,0,1,2.7};`

```
printf("%f", ar[++2]);
```

Q 1) can you please tell me why I am getting error: lvalue required as increment operand in gcc compiler in c language.

Q 2) why does  `int ar[] = {0,0,1,2.7};`

```
printf("%f", ar[3]);
```

output 0.000000? Is it because 2.7 cant be casted to integer? And it cant be casted to integer because integer is stored in small# of bytes in comparison to float?

What is the difference between `ar[i]++`, `ar[i++]`, `ar[++i]`?

Comment: Q1) Because you can only pre- or post-increment a *variable*.

Comment: `lvalue required as increment operand in gcc` Doesn't this explain anything to you?

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Comment: That's a happy mixture of unrelated questions. Every single one has been asked and answered before. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Q2) Because you pass an `int` to the `%f` format for `double`. None of this would happen if you pay attention to compiler warnings. Q2 uses an `int` array whereas Q1 used a `float` array, and you forgot to update the format spec.

Answer (score 1):

> Q 1) can you please tell me why i am getting error: lvalue required as increment operand in gcc compiler in c language.

Because literal value `2` is not an lvalue that you can modify. `++2` doesn't make sense.

> why does  int ar[] = {0,0,1,2.7};
>    printf("%f", ar[3]);

`ar` is an `int` array. So printing `ar[3]` using `%f` results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to incorrect format specifier. Use `%d` to print `int` values.

Comment: Changing `int ar[]` to `float ar[]` is probably closer to what they intended.

Answer (score 1):

> `printf("%f", ar[++2]);`
>
> Q 1) can you please tell me why I am getting error: lvalue required as increment operand in gcc compiler in c language.

For the same reason you can't write something like `2=3`.  The expression `2` is not associated with a region of memory, such that you can write a new value to it.

> Q 2) why does  `int ar[] = {0,0,1,2.7};
>
> printf("%f", ar[3]);`
> output 0.000000? Is it because 2.7 cant be casted to integer?

No.  The `2.7` would have been converted and stored as the integer value `2`.  The problem is that you're using the `%f` format specifier with an `int` argument, and thus the behavior is *undefined*.

You're basically telling `printf` to interpret the bit pattern `0x00000002` as a 64-bit `double`.  `0.000000` is one possible output, but far from the only one.

> What is the difference between ar[i]++, ar[i++], ar[++i]?

`ar[i]++` is roughly equivalent to `ar[i] = ar[i] + 1`.
`ar[i++]` is roughly equivalent to `ar[i]; i = i + 1`.
`ar[++i]` is roughly equivalent to `ar[i + 1]; i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The postfix and prefix operators are meant to be performed on `lvalues`, so `++2` is illegal and that is why you get

```
value required as increment operand in gcc
```

> What is an lvalue?

An argument that’s an `lvalue` is a data object that can be referenced by an address.

In your case, `2` is just a literal which can't be referenced by an address.

> What is the difference between ar[i]++, ar[i++], ar[++i]?

In very crude terms `x++(postfix)` means take the current value and then increment `x` and `++x(prefix)` means increment the value first and then take the result. So

```
x=ar[i]++; 
// means store the current value of ar[i] to x and then increment ar[i] by one
x=ar[i++]; 
// no difference except that you're applying the postfix to the index
x=ar[++i];
// Here take the incremented value of i and then compute ar[i]
x=ar[i++];
// Here take the current value of i to compute a[i] and then increment i by one
```